# How to add a strikethough or slash over the "Cal" of "CalParam"

Tags: text-decorations, strikeout

There are two types of parameters: calibrated and non-calibrated. I use "CalParam" as a shorthand to denote a calibrated parameter. To denote a non-calibrated paramter, I want to add a strikethrough or a slash over "Cal". I tried

> $\mathsf{\not CalParam}$

But it added a slash only over "C" rather than "Cal". :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `soul` -- short for "space out and underline" -- package provides a text-mode macro called `\st` which "strikes out" its argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul} % for "\st" macro
\newcommand{\CalParam}{\textsf{CalParam}}
\newcommand{\NotCalParam}{\textsf{\st{Cal}Param}}

\begin{document}
\CalParam{} vs.\ \NotCalParam
\end{document}
```